# Blender equalizes image references with different height dimensions

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, materials

In Photoshop I cropped two image segments from same image but with different variation in height, one segment is longer and one shorter.

For some reason if I import them in Blender as refs they become equalized in height. First image segment 142x519, second 141x683.

Can I make those refs not be equalized in height ?

[image: segment1]
[image: segment2]

[image: blender viewport]